# Combine two different unrelated SQL queries( returning single column results) into one query result with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql queries. In first I am returing total marks obtained and in other i am returning maximum marks . Now  i want to combine both in single query for the purpose of making it into single procedure. Queries are as :

First Query

```
   select SUM(MarksObtained) as MarksObtained from tbAnswers where QID IN(Select QID from tbQuestions where ExamID =2)
```

2nd Query

```
Select SUM(Marks) as MaxMarks from tbQuestions where ExamID =2
```

I want something like below to return:

```
Maxmarks | MarksObtained
------------------------
   100        50
```

I tried Union, but it returned something like below:

```
MarksObtained
-------------
100

50
```

Comment: using CTE, you can easily update query to get result GroupBy ExamID and not just for one ExamID

Comment: Well I am not using only 1 examId actually, it was just for test case. But since at one time i need only one examID, it is working fine for me. I am giving examID as parameter actually in stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the queries are unrelated, you can just throw them into the select:

```
SELECT
   (
      select SUM(MarksObtained)  
      from tbAnswers where QID IN (
          Select QID from tbQuestions where ExamID = 2
      )
   ) as MarksObtained,
   (
       Select SUM(Marks)   
       from tbQuestions where ExamID = 2
   ) as MaxMarks
```

Comment: Well i exactly did same and it worked and now saw ur help here. Still appreciate it

Comment: Your answer is perfect although there is no need of putting alias inside each sql query as we are putting same outside of each

Answer (score 1):

Even with accepted answer it is make sense to mention that probably the right thing to do is to use separate queries, as they are and just use MARS on the client, in case performance was an issue.

UPDATE: Thats how you can combine several queries and read them all together:

```
using(var conn = SqlConnection(...)) {
   conn.Open();
   var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
   cmd.CommandText = 
    @"Select SUM(MarksObtained) as MarksObtained 
      from tbAnswers 
      where QID IN(Select QID from tbQuestions where ExamID =2);"
  + @"Select SUM(Marks) as MaxMarks 
      from tbQuestions 
      where ExamID =2";

   using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader) {
        ... // read MarksObtained
        dr.NextResult()
        ... // readMaxMarks
        dr.Close()
   }
   conn.Close()
}
```

MSDN [IDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well in my scenerio, I am actually trying to increase performance as I need not call two different procedures for 2 different queries, instead only one procedure is enough, so maybe in terms of programming and variable i need to declare there, it is saving me good in terms of space and time . Still its difficult to make you understand under what circumstances I am actually executing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH    CTE1 ( MarksObtained )
              AS ( SELECT   SUM(MarksObtained) AS MarksObtained
                   FROM     tbAnswers
                   WHERE    QID IN ( SELECT QID
                                     FROM   tbQuestions
                                     WHERE  ExamID = 2 )
                 ),
            CTE2 ( MaxMarks )
              AS ( SELECT   SUM(Marks) AS MaxMarks
                   FROM     tbQuestions
                   WHERE    ExamID = 2
                 )
        SELECT  MaxMarks,MarksObtained
        FROM    CTE1 ,
                CTE2
```